# How to swizzle NSURLSession class method dataTaskWithUrl

Tags: ios, swift, swizzling, method-swizzling

I have been trying to swizzle NSURLSession class method dataTaskWithRequest but not been able to get it done

```
extension NSURLSession{
public override class func initialize() {
    struct Static {
        static var token: dispatch_once_t = 0
    }

    if self !== NSURLSession.self {
        return
    }

    dispatch_once(&Static.token) {
        let originalSelector = Selector("dataTaskWithRequest:completionHandler:")
        let swizzledSelector = Selector("my_dataTaskWithRequest:completionHandler:")

        let originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(self, originalSelector)
        let swizzledMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(self, swizzledSelector)

        let didAddMethod = class_addMethod(self, originalSelector, method_getImplementation(swizzledMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(swizzledMethod))

        if didAddMethod {
            class_replaceMethod(self, swizzledSelector, method_getImplementation(originalMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(originalMethod))
        } else {
            method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod)
        }
    }
}

// Swizzled Method
func my_dataTaskWithRequest(request: NSURLRequest,completionHandler: (NSData?, NSURLResponse?, NSError?)) -> NSURLSessionDataTask {

    print("Inside Swizzled Method")

    return my_dataTaskWithRequest(request,completionHandler: completionHandler)
}
}
```

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Are you sure your `initialize` is actually called? Anyway, you should implement `load`, not override `initialize`. [See this question for details.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13326435/nsobject-load-and-initialize-what-do-they-do).

Answer (score -1):

I had to upload my data in JSON(or NSDictionary )format to server.

I have done something like this...

```
let urlPath:String = apiURL + apiVersion + url + "?api_key=" + apiKey
//  OR
let urlPath:String = "your url string"
let url = NSURL(string: urlPath)
let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: {(data, reponse, error) in
println("Task completed")
// rest of the function...
})

task.resume()
```

For more or relative answer visit link
[How to swizzle in private method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22361427/how-to-swizzle-a-method-of-a-private-class?rq=1)

I hope it may help you

Comment: This question is tagged [tag:swift].  Why would you provide an answer in Objective-C?

Comment: I think it may give you idea... how to resolve your problem. I had ready code/solution from my previous project.  You can convert to swift.

Comment: Hello. The question is tagged "swift", please provide an answer in Swift, not in another language. Thanks!

Comment: Hey @EricD. This is swift code. Try it, it may help you!

Comment: I have asked how to swizzle the dataTaskWithURL method not how to use it. Please provide if you have solution for that @AvinashJadhav

Comment: Dear @ManuGupta I was provided you with my solution that was worked for me successfully, but you couldn't understood. Now solution changed.

Answer (score -1):

```
// i hope it may be help you
  extension NSURLSession{
  public override class func initialize() {
   struct Static {
      static var token: dispatch_once_t = 0
   }

  if self !== NSURLSession.self {
      return
  }

  dispatch_once(&Static.token) {
 let method1: Method = class_getInstanceMethod(self,Selector("dataTaskWithRequest:completionHandler:"));
 let method2 = class_getInstanceMethod(self, Selector("my_dataTaskWithRequest:completionHandler:"));
  method_exchangeImplementations(method1, method2);
}
}
// Swizzled Method
func my_dataTaskWithRequest(request: NSURLRequest,completionHandler: (NSData?, NSURLResponse?, NSError?)) -> NSURLSessionDataTask {

print("Inside Swizzled Method")

return my_dataTaskWithRequest(request,completionHandler: completionHandler)
}
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me, as you have done nothing different in your answer  just changed the way of writing selectors @Andey

Comment: I want to swizzle method in URLSession but not able to achieve. Can you please help me.

Comment: any of you done swizzling the method in URLSession please help me if done @ManuGupta